# How to 'puts' a number list of items in the array using an 'until' loop

Tags: ruby, loops, nokogiri

I am using loops and a counter to put out a numbered list of items. It lists them all at once under 1, and then 2 is another round of listing of all of the items.

The `while` loop doesn't work and I figured `until` was better. I also moved `counter` outside of the first iteriation but that doesn't work either.

```
require 'pry'
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class KefotoScraper::CLI
  def initialize
    @product_names = []
    @page_url = "https://kefotos.mx/"
  end

  def call
    puts "These are the services that Kefoto offers:"
    list_products
  end

  private

  def home_html
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(@page_url))
  end

  def service_names
    @service_names = home_html.css(".nav-link").map do |link|
      link['href'].to_s.gsub(/.php/, "")
    end

    @service_names.each do |pr|
      @product_names << pr
    end

    @product_names
  end

  def list_products
    i = 1
    n = 0

    until @product_names.length < n do
      @product_names.each {|list_item| puts "#{i} #{list_item}"}
      i += 1
      n += 1
    end
  end

  def service_links
    @service_links ||= home_html.css(".nav-item").map { |link| link['href'] }
  end
end
```

The list repeats itself over and over again.

```
[3] pry(#<KefotoScraper::CLI>)> @product_names
=> ["foto-enmarcada", "impresion-fotografica", "photobooks", "impresion-directa-canvas", "impresion-acrilico", "fotoregalos"]
[4] pry(#<KefotoScraper::CLI>)> list_products
1 foto-enmarcada
1 impresion-fotografica
1 photobooks
1 impresion-directa-canvas
1 impresion-acrilico
1 fotoregalos
2 foto-enmarcada
2 impresion-fotografica
2 photobooks
2 impresion-directa-canvas
2 impresion-acrilico
2 fotoregalos
```

Comment: I have reformatted your indentation and line breaks. This makes your code much easier to read, both for you and for us.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to use proper grammar when posing a question or providing an answer. SO isn't a message board, instead it's more of an online encyclopedia of programming problems and solutions, where grammar counts because we're educating future users seeking a solution to the same problem you encountered. That effort pays off for us all.

Answer (score 2):

```
def list_products
  @product_names.each_with_index do |list_item, i|
    puts "#{i} #{list_item}"
  end
end
```

edit: thanks for the feedback, the Tin Man.
With your current code, you're looping through `@product_names` once with `until` and inside of that you're looping through `@product_names` with `.each`. For example if `@product_names.length == 3`, you'd print `3 * 3 == 9` times!

Since you only need to loop through `@product_names` once, pick either `until` or `.each`. My example above uses `.each` and here is an example using `until`:

```
i = 1
until @product_names.length < i do
  puts "#{i} #{@product_names[i-1]}"
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That works in pry but it doesn't puts it when i call the method on the "call" method. basically I am just getting this in the terminal::  ```These are the services that Kefoto offers:  ```          and then it ends

Comment: Is `@product_names` empty?

Comment: no in pry i do get the list. not outside of pry. maybe i need to move the call method to the end of the file and start with the other methods? it feels like its going one by one

Comment: yes product services is nil but it populates once i call in the service_names method several times on pry

Comment: in your `call` method, run `service_names` first to populate your `@product_names` before you `list_products`

Comment: '''[1] pry(#<KefotoScraper::CLI>)> @product_names
=> []
[2] pry(#<KefotoScraper::CLI>)> service_names
=> ["foto-enmarcada", "impresion-fotografica", "photobooks", "impresion-directa-canvas", "impresion-acrilico", "fotoregalos"]
[3] pry(#<KefotoScraper::CLI>)> @product_names
=> ["foto-enmarcada", "impresion-fotografica", "photobooks", "impresion-directa-canvas", "impresion-acrilico", "fotoregalos"] ```

Comment: Don't just toss out code, explain how it works and why it's a good solution. The idea is to educate so the OP doesn't have to ask again, but instead understands how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: the Tin Man, responded to your comment with an edit in my original answer